# Usar datos del Array por separado cada valor para un método

Tags: java, java-8

tengo una duda quiero usar un método en este caso "**sendUserEmail**" que sea usado por cada valor del array **destinatarios**, hacer un bucle hasta que haya enviado a cada valor del array, o sea a cada destinatario por separado.

El método es más o menos así, pero **destinatarios** me llega como array, ¿cómo podría ponerlo en el método sendUserEmail para enviarlo por cada valor del array? :

```
List<UserDataModel> listEmails = userDataJpaRepository.findAllByUserCode(policy.getUserCode());
String[] destinitarios= listEmails.stream().map(UserDataModel::getEmail).toArray(String[]::new);
emailOperation.sendUserEmail(userIdentity, getUserName(policy.getUserCode()), 
            createDate, patientName, numberProduct, nameProduct, destinitarios);
```

Comment: ya intentaste con `listEmails.stream().map(UserDataModel::getEmail).forEach((mail) -> emailOperation.sendUserEmail(userIdentity, getUserName(policy.getUserCode()),
                createDate, patientName, numberProduct, nameProduct, mail));` ????

Comment: gracias, eso me sirvió